# Would increasing Fan speed help AC cooling

Tags: hvac

I have 5 Ton AC  and 5 Ton air handler, and according to me both are functioning with in the specs (but what do I know)

Unfortunately I live in the oven (Arizona)

What can I do to improve the cooling

Outdoor is 110 F day to day and it does not cool down much overnight (90F)

The AC  runs all the time when inside Temp is set to 81F

When I set the temp to 83F, it shows about 50/50 cycling, which is good, but not happy with 83F indoor.

Now to the **question**

The only thing I think I can do is to increase the air handler Fan speed from Medium to High speed.

Is it safe to do that or should I look for problems.

It is a two story 2800 sq ft so the AC is maxed out with high ceilings and flat roof, dual pane windows. So I have no ducts exposed.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147743/discussion-on-question-by-ruskes-would-increasing-fan-speed-help-ac-cooling); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it

I did not clean my condenser for 5 years

Comment: *and according to me both are functioning with in the specs*

Comment: @ron I said 'according to me`

Answer (score 2):

You mention 50/50 duty cycle giving you 83 degF inside. To get to a comfortable temperature in the whole house you will likely have to go to a 100/0 duty cycle and there is nothing wrong with that. In fact it is easier on the compressor, contactors and everything to run continuously. It is running up the electric consumption, but if you can pay that bill for one or two months, then your HVAC is working just as expected.

Our 4 ton 17 SEER unit in our 2000 sqft house in Dallas is on 100% duty cycle during the heat of the day today because I have the thermostat set on 73 degF and it is maintaining 74 degF. The official outside temp is 104 degF.

Comment: Some differences. If I set it to 81 it runs all day long newer reaching the set point (it newer turns off). I can not reach below 80.

Comment: Something wrong then. Is the suction line cold at the bottom of the condensing unit? What is the refrigerant? You need a professional inspection.

Answer (score 1):

First be sure all units and filters are clean. Upping the fan speed may help but be cautious and monitor the refrigerant return temperature first before then after the change. You could easily over load it especially when it is hot. The first thing I did was install ceiling fans, they made a big difference. I replaced the roof (it was going bad) and added a Ridge vent, that made a huge difference. You could check into a power vent system or adding more vents.

Since you have no HVAC upstairs you could add a split and add some cooling there to help cool that down and probably make sleeping much easier.

It will come down to either adding more cooling or less heat maybe even both.

Hint: The hot coil is the condenser, the cold coil is the evaporator. The smaller line is the liquid from the condenser to the evaporator and the large line is from the evaporator to the compressor. You want to measure the temperature of the larger line.

Comment: What is the temperature of the suction line supposed to be and where should this be measured?

Comment: Makes sense what you say. However the return goes into the condenser, so do I measure it there